# php include variables without including

Tags: php, variables

Can some one tell me how to "include" a variable from another .php file without all its other content.

index.php

```
<?php
$info=file('somedir/somefile.php');
$v1=trim($info[2]);
$v2=trim($info[3]);
$v3=trim($info[4]);
?>
```

the somedir/somefile.php

```
<?php
$variable=something;
$variable2=someotherting;
$variable3=thirdone!;
All the other content there may not be runned or showed.
?>
```

Can anybody please help me??

**Edit:**

Its for my dynamic page.

```
<html>
    <?php
    include_once 'config.php';
    include_once 'includes/mysqlconnect.php';
    $url_slash=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url= rtrim($url_slash, '/');
    //$url = basename($url);
    $info=file('sites/'.$url.'.php');
    $title=trim($info[2]);
    ?>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>$title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $domain;?>themes/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $domain;?>themes/<?php echo $theme;?>.css">
    </head>
    <body class="body">
        <div class="container-all">
            <?php include_once 'includes/header.php';?>
            <div class="container">
                <?php include_once 'includes/navigationbar.php';?>
                <?php include_once 'includes/rightsidebar.php';?>
                <div class="content"><?php

                if ($url==''){

                    include_once "sites/home.php";
                }
                elseif (file_exists("sites/$url.php") && is_readable('/var/www/html/sites/'.$url.'.php')){
                    include_once '/var/www/html/sites/'.$url.'.php';

                }

                else {
                    include_once 'sites/404.php';

                }


                ?></div>
                <?php include_once 'includes/footer.php';?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope you understand my question now.

Comment: save in session and use it on other page.

Comment: does somefile.php have to be PHP, or is it just a file containing data?

Comment: Depends on your needs, you can use a superglobals ($_GET, $_POST or $_SESSION).

Comment: What I need is to get some content from ONLY one line of antoher file and turn it into a variable

Answer (score 3):

Programming is just driving your thoughts :)

So what i want to say that your question is how you can include just some part of an included file and my answer is that you can achieve that by doing a test each time the main file is included from withing this file to see if the file is included internally or not and you can be more precise in a way that you split your main file into block which are loaded due suitable variable

Take a look for this workaround and hope you will understand what i mean

Supposing we have the main file named main.php contains that contents

```
<?php
     echo 'I am a java programmer';
     echo 'I know also PHP very well';
     echo 'When the jquery is my preferred toast !';
?>
```

now i have three external files that will include that file each file is specific for one of this 3 programming language

So i will create my 3 files in this way :

File : java.php

```
<?php
    $iamjavadevelopper = 1;
    include_once("main.php");
?>
```

File : phpfav.php

```
<?php
    $iamphpdevelopper = 1;
    include_once("main.php");
?>
```

File : jquery.php

```
<?php
    $iamjquerydevelopper = 1;
    include_once("main.php");
?>
```

and my main.php will be coded in this way

```
<?php
    if(isset($iamjavadevelopper))
        echo 'I am a java programmer';
    if(isset($iamphpdevelopper))
        echo 'I know also PHP very well';
    if(isset($iamjquerydevelopper))
     echo 'When the jquery is my preferred toast !';
?>
```

By this way each one of our three external files will show just a part of the included file :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of without cookies or session's is to make an `if` condition in the page.

like that:
index.php

`<?php include('somedir/somefile.php');?>`

the somedir/somefile.php

```
<?php
if ($pageName != 'somefile.php')    {
    $variable=something;
    $variable2=someotherting;
    $variable3=thirdone!;
}   else    {
    // All the other content
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the variables in a separate file that can be included separately. Do it the sane way. Structure your code properly, don't try to invent solutions for problems you have because your structure is messy.